# ActiveAdmin assets loading in production env

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3.2, activeadmin

For some reason, some activeadmin's assets (js scripts) can't be loaded for production env.

I have code to initialize the js.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('ready');
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();
});
```

The problem is that it never starts, but if I register a file with this code, it starts working, but all the required js is not loaded.

```
#active_admin.js
//= require active_admin/base
//= require highlight_js/highlight
//= require highlight_js/languages/xml
//= require highlight_js/languages/json

#init.js
$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log('ready'); # <- never executes, unless init.js is places to active_admin.rb
    hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad(); # if init.js is places to active_admin.rb then we get an error 'hljs' is unknown object
});

#active_admin.rb
  config.register_javascript 'init.js'
```

Comment: What about add another line `//= require init` ? Is that working?

Comment: @nayiaw there is that line

Comment: I don't see it here. Not the line with `register_javascript`, they are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I rearranged require js section and got it worked. But some moments are still mysterious.